# How to login in terminal using ctrl+alt+ f1-f6?

Tags: virtual-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and sometimes the windows environment crashes. But, I am still able to move the mouse and call the tty windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1-6</kbd> keys. But I am never able to login sucessfully.

I can call the terminal icon in the windows and make a root login. But when the terminal is called with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>fx</kbd> keys it always gives invalid login. How to make a login this way and how to reset the windows environment (to cancel the crash)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your username is the one before the @ mark on prompt.

Like, mine is `ronnie@acer-TM-PLAY`. So, my username is ronnie
and the password you know.

When you enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> keys You **have** to enter that username and the password assigned to it.

Hope it helped

Comment: it does not appears any @ character. Only this: nuno-belas login: But i write nuno-belas then the password and it does not work.

Comment: You should use `nuno` as user (if that is your username) and then enter your password.

Answer (score 1):

I had to open a terminal window using the icon in the windows environment and then i login with root.
I used the useradd to add the user and then the command passwd to define a password. Then it worled.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Username has to be all simple. My username was Aux-146. I had to use aux-146 for login. And it works. Hope this helps.